# PHPUnit Test with host/useragent which defined in config.yml

Tags: symfony, configuration, phpunit

I want to define the Test-Client useragent and hostname in my config.yml.

At the moment I use the same things in each configuration:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
$client->setServerParameters(
    array(
        'HTTP_HOST' => 'Test',
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'Test'
    )
);
```

And I wish to use something like this

```
$client = static::createClient();
$container = $client->getContainer();
$client->setServerParameters(
    array(
        'HTTP_HOST' => $container->getParameter('test.host'),
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => $container->getParameter('test.useragent')
    )
);
```

But that fails.

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "test" in config.yml. Looked for namespace "test", found "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doctrine" [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your values to the `parameter.yml`.

In general, just putting values into comfig.yml does not automatically add them to your container.

If you want to learn how you can make your code configurable via config.yml have a look at [How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)